# How to swap Erc20 to Eth with uniswap v3 router?

Tags: ethereum, uniswap

Uniswap v3 doesn't have a function to perform ERC20 to ETH swap.

I am currently working on a project involving token swapping. We initially used Uniswap V2, but as Uniswap V3 is better, we decided to migrate to it. However, we have been unable to find a function in Uniswap V3 that facilitates ERC20 to ETH swaps, similar to the **swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens **function in V2.

How can I perform ERC20 to ETH swaps in Uniswap V3?

Comment: `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` [note that Uniswap v3 does not support transfer fee tokens at all](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/token-tax), so finding equivalent function is impossible.

Comment: ok, but I want a way to do this ERC20 to ETH swapping, is this not possible with V3 router? if not how they are doing on there swapping platform?

Comment: Uniswap V3's Universal Router supports wrapping and unwrapping ETH. https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/universal-router/technical-reference - however their documentation does not tell how to use it, so I suggest you chase Uniswap developers directly

Comment: You should be able to unwrap weth using a multicall

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can swap ETH for ERC20 tokens with uniswap V3 (router contract)
The functions for a swap on the router contract are all payable, it means that from a smart contract that wants to perform a swap, you will need to act like u want to swap WETH (put the WETH address on the tokenIn input) and send the ETH amountIn to the router contract

example:

```
contract Swap {

receive() external payable {}

address public constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
ISwapRouter public constant swapRouter = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

function swapExactInputSingleETH(
    address tokenOut,
    uint256 amountOutMinimum
) external payable returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    address tokenIn = WETH;
    uint256 amountIn = msg.value;

    ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params =
                        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams({
            tokenIn: tokenIn,
            tokenOut: tokenOut,
            fee: 3000,
            recipient: msg.sender,
            deadline: block.timestamp,
            amountIn: amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum: amountOutMinimum,
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
        });

    // The call to `exactInputSingle` executes the swap.
    amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle{value: amountIn}(params);
    }
}
```

It defo works for ETH as TokenIn but I don't know how to sxap erc20 tokens for ETH.

If you use exactOutput with that method, you wont receive the extra ETH back so be aware

Answer (score 0):

To swap ERC20 for ERC20 or ETH you have to transfer money from the contract of your sell token and approve for selling them to uniswap router contract.

Answer (score 0):

On [1Inch](https://portal.1inch.dev) you can use placeholder `0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE` as ETH token address. Probably, the same for the Uniswap. Answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87352/why-does-this-address-have-a-balance)